# Jenkins string variable to Ansible string variable

Tags: variables, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

may I ask if there is a way where jenkins string variable can be handled by Ansible when triggering the playbook? I noticed that when I passed the string variable of Jenkins to Ansible the variable becomes incomplete. let say the variable is:

> **VARIABLE = deploying my version**

And jenkins will trigger this command on pipeline:

```
ansible-playbook -D my-playbook.yml -e "VARIABLE=${params.VARIABLE}"
```

Instead of seeing this output:

> **deploying my version**

I'm actually getting this as the result:

> **deploying**

The other keywords are gone, please let me know if you have any ideas on fixing this. Thanks

Comment: this seems to be more related to the way jenkins is treating the space separated variable. Try using a simple shell command to echo the value! Space separated values I think might need some tweak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible. It looks like just syntax:

```
ansible-playbook -D my-playbook.yml -e ' VARIABLE="${params.VARIABLE}" '
```